# How to prevent apache from forcing HTTPS in mod_rewrite redirects?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

So I am setting up an onion domain with reverse proxy to apache2 server, and this means that contrary to the current trends I need to use http everywhere. This does not affect security at all, there is no need for https on .onion domains.

So I ran into this issue - when I specify redirection without http:// in .htaccess, it will force https anyways.

This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ssltest$ / [L,R=302]
```

and when I access http://myonionwebsite.onion/ssltest I get this Header in reply from server:

```
Location: https://myonionwebsite.onion/
```

instead of

```
Location: http://myonionwebsite.onion/
```

which I would expect.

It is very confusing, do you have any idea what could be causing this?

See curl:

```
curl 'http://myonionwebsite.onion/ssltest'
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://myonionwebsite.onion/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Any reason what can be causing this and how to disable it? Keep in mind that I use only .htaccess with relative URL for the redirect, so it should use whatever domain/protocol that is used for the request. This is also completely unrelated to tor, if I used .com domain it would work the same way.

Comment: If you have access, did you check httpd.conf or the virtual server configuration?

Comment: Why do you not force it then?  If it works, use it and move on :-)  Somewhere in the other configuration files, there are some directives that force https.  If you cannot view and edit those, forcing it will be your only option.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the HTTP to HTTPS redirect is being forced elsewhere (httpd.conf maybe), or your browser still has the redirect cached.

I'm doing something similar where I have a clearnet website that's also available as a .onion. I want HTTP to redirect to HTTPS, but only for the clearnet website. The .onion doesn't need HTTPS.
The mod-rewrite solution that works for me is:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !.onion$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

That basically says if the port is 80 (HTTP), then redirect all requests to HTTPS, unless the requested host ends with .onion